# How are lots with partial shares handled when transferring a position between brokerages?

Tags: united-states, brokerage, account-transfer

When doing an in-kind transfer of a position between two brokerages, how are lots with partial shares (from dividend reinvestment) handled?  For example, if I owned 513.7696 shares of XYZ that were split across 5 lots as follows:

```
Lot  Shares
  1  500.0000
  2    2.8965
  3    3.1879
  4    4.5525
  5    3.1327
```

will I:

A)  have 513 shares transferred and the cash for the remaining .7696 share?
or
B)  have 512 shares transferred and the cash for the remaining 1.7696 shares?

If the answer is B, is there a way to reacquire most of the partial shares without any tax implications?

I asked my current brokerage, but all they said was that they do not transfer partial shares.

Comment: I am guessing, since this really depends on how the broker handles it, but I would suspect (A) for the same reasons that brokers are able to deal with fractional shares at all. But I'm not sure why you should care; capital gains tax on that single round-off share is probably insignificant, and the worst that happens is you repurchase one more share.

Comment: @keshlam that should have been an answer

Comment: Didn't feel a guess qualified as an Answer, even a reasonable SWAG. Feel free to paraphrase, or swipe,  if you can confirm.

Comment: I can confirm empirically, but I agree that it depends on the brokers on both sides

Comment: Why would they *not* transfer the 513th whole share?  (What’s special about it, as opposed to the 512th?)

Comment: Good point. Purchase dates)lits is relevant record-keeping for tax purposes, but what you _own_ is 513.whatevet shares, not the lots.

Comment: @keshlam If it's option A then I don't care.  The fractional share(s) are insignificant.  But if it's option B then I'm looking at anywhere from 5 to 13 shares (plus the fraction) depending on the position, which is starting to get significant to me.  I should know more next month after talking with the new broker and will add an answer once I find out more.